# How to use WHERE function in Firebase using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Actual Goal:

1. User can post in Organization Group, the post that is posted in that Organization Group must not be visible in other Organization Group so I tried to use the WHERE function in Firebase to filter the Post Lists.
2. The every post made by the user will save the Organization Group ID (where the post is created) in the Firestore. So when I filter the lists of posts I can used the Organization Group ID(postOrgId) to filter specific posts made in each Org Group.

I guess I have a problem in getting the Organization ID viewed by the user using the Activated Route.

[image: OrgID]

Image 1: Organization ID

I try the following.

1. I try to use Activated Route because it will saved the current Org Group ID viewed by the user but unfortunately Firebase throws an error.
2. I made a method that gets the current Org ID.

[image: Error Message]

Image 2: Firebase throws an error

Heres the **Organization Group (org-home.ts)**

```
export class OrgHomePage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  loadOrganization: Organization;
  orgId: any;

  orgSub: Subscription;

  posts: Post[];
  isLoading = false;


  constructor(private orgService: OrganizationService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService,
    public auth: AuthService,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
    private postService: PostService) {}//

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    //This will read the Organization Group ID
    this.orgId = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['orgID'];

    // I call the method and passed the Org ID
    this.postService.getOrgId(this.orgId);

    this.orgSub = this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });

  }
```

Heres the **Post Service (post.service.ts)**

```
export class PostService {
  postCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  postDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;
  post: Observable<Post>;

  post$: any;

  orgId: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore
    ) {


    this.postCol = this.afs.collection('post', ref => ref.orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));

    //Organization Group ID will be passed here to the WHERE Clause
    this.postCol = this.afs.collection('post', ref => ref.where("postOrgId", "==", this.orgId));

    this.posts = this.postCol.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(action => {
        return action.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
          data.postId = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        })
      })
    );
   }//

   //Gets all post
   getPosts() {
     return this.posts;
   }

   //It will get the Organization ID
   getOrgId(idParameter): Observable<any>{
    return this.orgId = this.afs.collection('post', result => result.where('postOrgId', '==', idParameter)).valueChanges();
   }
```

Comment: Can you make sure `this.orgID` is defined/

Comment: In my post service, this.orgID wasnt read so I guess I have a problem to get the current organization ID viewed by user.

Answer (score 0):

When I work with Angular and Firebase I do it like this:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){}

someFunction(idParameter): Observable<any>{
 return this.afs.collection('Collection', result => result.where('fieldThatContainsTheId', '==', idParameter)).valueCahnges();
}
```

Comment: Where I can I put this sir, in my Post Service?

Comment: yes, put in your Post Service and call it from your component. This is the way I do it when I have to retrieve documents from Firestore collections.

Comment: I try what you said sir but unfortunately, error still exists. I will post the updated code.